# send javascript array to controller and load view

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

Sorry I'm a newbie in web programming. I have a problem to send array from Javascript / JS array to my function in controller and load new view.

I try to use ajax and I can read that array but ajax not load new view, how to do that?

Please tell me the correct way to send javascript array to controller and load new view.

Please help.

Here's my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/test/coba",
    data: { 
        test: "test"
    }
});
```

and my controller test.php

```
function coba() {
    $data['test'] = $this->input->post('test');
    $this->load->view('newview',$data);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is meant to send or receive data from the client side to the server side. You can't display a view by using an AJAX method, what you could do, however, is receive values that could then be displayed by using Javascript code.

But AJAX is mainly used to give the client the possibility to interact with the database, which doesn't seem to be what you are trying to do, are you sure you need to use AJAX?

If you need to display something depending on user behaviour, without requiring database calls, then Javascript should be all you need. You could add the HTML code with PHP, and hide it, and when the user does the specific action, you can fill what needs to be filled and display your content.

Comment: not should ajax , what i need is just send javascript array to controller and load new view , how to do that ? @Dany Caissy

Comment: You shouldn't do that, that's the problem. You should normally have your data available through PHP. If the content is different depending on user behavior, then you can do most of this in Javascript. In the cases that you need to use the database, then you have to use AJAX, but we can't help you without more information.

Comment: @Downvoter, if you have a better answer, have at it.

Comment: yes , but my problem is the array from datatables plugin function in javascript and i need to use that array in other view @Dany Caissy